# If I download a file from safari to a location that is an FTP/SFTP server will it be downloaded directly to the server?

Tags: ios, safari, file-transfer, ftp, sftp

I have an SFTP server mounted to my iPhone’s filesystem with the help of a third party application. If I download a file from safari will it be downloaded to my device and then uploaded to the server or will it go directly from site’s server to said SFTP server?